# Is it ok to reclaim OP for unaccepting my answer and accepting his own answer based on mine?

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a question which was accepted as correct by the OP and actually thanked me for helping him solve his problem in the comments to my answer.

A day later he posted his own answer, still giving me credit, but stating that it was a "Refined answer" with a small change based on the knowledge he has of his own problem and then accepts it as the correct answer. Don't get me wrong, I like just being able to help others, but I think I deserved those +15 reputation that were taken away.

Is there some regulation about this? What to do in a case like this?

Comment: It's entirely up to the OP to decide. 15 measly points won't kill you. ;) (Says the guy with orders of magnitude more... ^_^;;)

Comment: Is it [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174234/sql-server-for-xml-path-vary-tags-dynamically/30177131#30177131)?

Comment: Yes, that's the question

Comment: You're right @deceze, I probably should let it go..just wondering if this is a common thing

Comment: Yes, I think it's fairly common.  It's happened to me plenty.  And that's fine.  The question author should accept the answer they found most helpful.

Comment: I gave it an upvote, so you have 10 of your imaginary internet points back :-) Nice answer by the way !

Comment: This is common. So is an asker accepting someone else's answer that was based on yours, accepting a newer answer that's just a copy of yours, never accepting or up-voting the answer at all even if they tell you it solved their problem, and unaccepting your answer because they ran into a new problem unrelated to the original question. However, if it is an answer that helps other people, it will eventually get up-voted.

Comment: What OP did is justified.Anyways you lost `15` but got `at least 50` due to this post.(Add 10 of my own).So a win -win situation :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but guys, how uneven of us to treat this question so much better than [this very similar one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292000/576767), probably because op is so much newer to this place. As a matter of fact... this is pretty much a duplicate...

Comment: I've done this recently. @SteveTranby spent a while helping me out, and while it wasn't the perfect answer it helped me solve my problem. Once I had totally and completely solved my question, I answered my question and accepted it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884531/how-to-add-a-label-to-a-progresstimers-sprite-in-cocos2dx

Comment: I had a guy get mad at me I made my own answer even though it was based off of his. He then went on to delete his answer. His answer wasn't as precise as I needed it to be. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026095/how-to-make-a-time-series-start-at-0-in-hours

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no regulations on what the OP should mark as the accepted answer.  Accepted answers are whatever the OP personally finds the most useful (however they come to that decision).

There is one piece of etiquette that applies to this situation.  Since the OP wrote another answer that is based on yours, the OP likely found your answer useful.  Anytime someone finds your answer useful, they would be justified (even encouraged) to upvote your helpful answer.  So (if they haven't already and have the privilege) the OP should strongly consider upvoting your helpful answer.

Answer (score 26):

When you search for answers to your questions, do you want the best, most complete answers at the top, or do you want the answers that they were based on at the top?  You don't deserve those 15 reputation points if a better answer is posted, even if it is based on yours.

Don't get attached to your imaginary internet points. They can be taken away as easily as they're given.

Comment: This does not apply?  A self-answer doesn't bubble "to the top" from being accepted.

Comment: @Yakk his point is that because an answer was once on top doesn't mean it'll always be on top. If the OP used a better answer, then that answer will eventually be on top.

Comment: These "imaginary Internet points" [seem to have a relationship](https://www.statwing.com/demos/dev-survey#workspaces/87347) with one's compensation. You can't tell cause and effect from this, but it's certainly a motivation to be attached to those points.

Comment: @mason I think it's pretty obvious that the causality is reversed.  Good programmers with both earn more money, and more rep.  They aren't earning more money because of their rep.

Comment: @Servy That may be obvious now - but let's say employers see this (I know I saw it mentioned in several news outlets) and realize that screening for reputation on Stack Overflow is a quick way to find well qualified employees - I know I'd do that if I was a recruiter. It's kind of the point of Stack Overflow Careers. This makes it easier for people with 10K reputation to get hired into good jobs, and therefore end up with better compensation. So while currently it may be as you say, I don't think that your reason for causality will always be the case.

Comment: @mason So people should be motivated to do something because it's possible for the a fundamental structure of our industry to change at some point in the future?  I don't think so.  If/when the programming industry becomes one in which what you describe is a reality *then* it would become a motivation.

Comment: @Servy It's a job race. You do what you need to do to be competitive. Is there a chance a potential employer may stumble across or actively search for my Stack Overflow account? Then you can bet I'm going to be motivated to make sure it properly represents me. And I think other people will think the same. Maybe not everyone, but definitely some, and therefore reputation points have real value.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there some regulation about this?

There isn't and there shouldn't be.

> What to do in a case like this?

Be graceful about it. Let's hope that the OP at least upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really agree with the current answers (they are not complete).

The OP here clearly states that the refined answer was "...a small change based on the knowledge he has of his [other OP] own problem".

Two possibilities (disregarding bad answers):

1. The person who provided the first answer did a lot of work to come up with an answer, and the original OP improved on it.
2. The person who provided the first answer did all the work to come up with a general answer, and original OP just adapted/added to it and created an answer only useful for himself.

The current answers of @Bill and @R Sahu are fine in the first case, but I have the feeling that case 2 is different and could use regulation. Answers should always be for the greater good, that is, a general answer useful for people in the next years to come should be preferred.

In fact, a good alternative would be to just edit and accept the answer (perhaps add a heading for the particular case)! That would be the fair thing to do.

Comment: A lot of people asking questions won't have the right to edit an answer. And I'm not sure that would be a good thing to promote.